# C++ Boost serialization of a matrix of vectors

Tags: c++, matrix, serialization, vector, boost

I'm using `<boost/serializaton>`, and I need to serialize a matrix of vectors, member of a class X1, say:

```
vector<vector<vector<vector<X2>>>> V;
```

where:

- V is initialized as V[N][M][S] by the X1's constructor.
- X2 is a class, owning some members and getter/setters, has its own serialize() function (which serializes two std::strings) and it's also initialized by the X1's constr.

The question is: **how can I serialize V?**

I tried different approaches but no one worked. I have read the documentation in the Boost site and its examples, but I’m missing something though.
Here it is the thing:

```
    #include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
    #include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
    #include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

    // I tried with the simplest way:
    class X1{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & V;
        }
    //…
    }; 

    // or by calling serialization in a explicit way for each object of V:            
    class X1{ 
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & V;
            for (auto it = V.begin(); it != V.end(); ++it) {
            ar & *it;
                for (auto jt = (*it).begin(); jt != (*it).end(); ++jt) {
                ar & *jt;
                    for (auto kt = (*jt).begin(); kt != (*jt).end(); ++kt) {
                    ar & *kt;
                        for (auto wt = (*kt).begin(); wt != (*kt).end(); ++wt) {
                        ar & *wt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    //…
    };
```

I tried the latter (maybe I should do it reversely?) also using ranges, and other different ways too that honestly I have deleted and don’t remember: it serializes but crashes when reading from the serialized file.
I hope to have expressed myself clearly, it’s my first question. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Anyone told you before that using such data structures is a very bad idea? If not, let me be the first. The right way to do this is to create a flat array, and an accessor method that will calculate the position of the element you need from its indices. Then if you do that, you won't need quadrillion loops and serialization will become trivial and performance will benefit from this.

Comment: Yes, I knew I could do it with flat arrays, but I wanted to use the STL containers for easing the task, since performance for this serialization is mandatory, as I will serialize V once for all. Anyway, if I won't make it work, I will follow your advise. Thank you.

Comment: You can still use STL containers with 1-dimensional array. There's nothing wrong with `vector<X2>`.

Comment: Ops, I mean "since performance for this serialization is not important"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vector support is builtin, so

```
template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & V;
    }
```

is the right thing for the datastructure.

Comment: So the serialization is implicitly recursive, since a vector containing vectors calls for vector serializations, and so on?

Comment: @expiring_noob Yes. Serialization dispatch is by ADL, container serialization only specifies the container-part, but dispatches on the element objects. There are some optimizations (e.g. for know bitwise serializable things) - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#bitwise

Comment: Yes, it's working! I had to serialize the dimensions of V (i.e. N, M, S in V[N][M][S]), and then add to the constructor of X1 that takes data from the serialized V, also its dimensions. Can't upvote you having not enough reputation, but thank you!

Comment: I don't see why you'd need doubly serialize the dimensions, but I'm sure it's not hurting. Maybe you need if to avoid having to deduce it back from the `vector<vector<vector<T>>>`. But that's just back to what @TheQuantumPhysicist said right away :)